# Flutter: How to get the size of a child widget in an overlay before it is rendered to use it in its parent's layout?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

## TL;DR

I have a parent that depends on the size of a child and that child is in the overlay and is not rendered until the parent is pressed, how can I get the child's size before rendering to layout the parent correctly?

## Details

I edited flutter's `PopupMenuButton` and created a [custom `PopupButton`](https://gist.github.com/Haidar0096/dd1569b71dae85cae0ec9e5661dc3651) that takes a `child`, `content`, and an `offsetBuilder`.

It can show the `content` on an `Overlay` when `child` is pressed. The content's position on the overlay is determined according to the offset returned from `offsetBuilder` as here:

```
             PopupButton(
              child: Container(
                child: const Text('MMMMMMMMMMM\nMMMMMMMMMMM\nMMMMMMMMMMM',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60), maxLines: 10,),
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
              ),
              content: popupContent,
              offsetBuilder: (size) {
                // size is the size of the child above
                return Offset((size.width - 500) / 2, 0.0);
              },
            )
```

the offset returned above translates `content` starting from the top left of the `child` as here:

[image]

I need to know the size of the `content` (the blue row) in order to place it above the `child` (the `Text` widget above) like here (where the offset is hardcoded):
[image]

The problem is that `content` is not actually rendered until I press on the `Text` so using `GlobalKey` in the code above will not work because when the code above executes the  `conten` is still not actually rendered and `Size` returned by the global key will be zero or null.

Also, using [this solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14488#issuecomment-561521697) may solve the problem but will render the widgets wrong for 1 frame and then everything will be correct (it is using `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`).

How can I get the size of `content` to use it in `offsetBuilder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most CLEAN and OPTIMAL way to do it, but I could solve it using `CustomSingleChildLayout` widget. This widget takes a child and delegates its layout to some `SingleChildLayoutDelegate` as per the documentation. So all I had to do in this case is send this `SingleChildLayoutDelegate` the `Size` and `Offset` of the popup button and then do the calculations in the `getPositionForChild` method of the delegate.
However this forced me to refactor the `PopupButton`'s code to accept in its constructor a `ContentBuilder` which is the function to be called inside the `PopupButton` and that will pass the button `Size` and `Offset` and get the `CustomSingleChildLayout` widget.

This is the `CustomSingleChildLayout` class:

```
    class PopupContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final Size popupButtonSize;
  final Offset popupButtonOffset;

  const PopupContent({
    Key? key,
    required this.popupButtonSize,
    required this.popupButtonOffset,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final moc = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return CustomSingleChildLayout(
      delegate: PopupContentSingleChildLayoutDelegate(
        popupButtonSize: popupButtonSize,
        popupButtonOffset: popupButtonOffset,
        padding: moc.padding,
      ),
      child: ... the blue row,
    );
  }
}

class PopupContentSingleChildLayoutDelegate extends SingleChildLayoutDelegate {
  final Size popupButtonSize;
  final Offset popupButtonOffset;
  final EdgeInsets padding;

  PopupContentSingleChildLayoutDelegate({
    required this.popupButtonSize,
    required this.popupButtonOffset,
    required this.padding,
  });

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(covariant SingleChildLayoutDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return this != oldDelegate;
  }

  @override
  Offset getPositionForChild(Size size, Size childSize) {
    Offset offset = Offset((popupButtonSize.width - childSize.width) / 2, 0);
    offset = popupButtonOffset
        .translate(offset.dx, offset.dy)
        .translate(0, -childSize.height);

    // Find the ideal vertical position.
    double y = offset.dy;

    // Find the ideal horizontal position.
    double x = offset.dx;

  ...some other calculations

    return Offset(x, y);
  }
}
```

and this is how I call it now

```
PopupButton(
              child: Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
                child: Text(text,
                    maxLines: 3, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 60)),
              ),
              contentBuilder: (size, offset) => PopupContent(
                popupButtonOffset: offset,
                popupButtonSize: size,
              ),
            )
```

now it works, but maybe its time the code be abstracted more and cleaned up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use LayoutBuilder to get size datas of the parent widget. Here is the example:

```
Container(
   width: _mainWidth,
   height: _mainHeight,
   color: Colors.blue,
   child: Center(
       child: LayoutBuilder(
           builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
               return Container(
                 width: constraints.maxWidth / 2,
                 height: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
                 color: Colors.yellow,
               );},
           ),
       ),
   ),
```

constraints can give you width and height info. In the example above, child widget's size is half of it's parent.

Comment: The question is actually the opposite, the parent depends on the size of the child so LayoutBuilder is useless