# How to make Gestures pass through a PopupRoute in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am pushing a route which extends `PopupRoute` (which extends `ModalRoute`) on the navigator. This route does not cover the whole screen with its content widgets. But it is absorbing all the gestures even those not covered by its contents due to its barrier adjusted by the parent `ModalRoute`. Is there a simple way to pass the gestures that happen on "empty areas" on this route to the route under it (behind it)??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71960095/flutter-how-to-get-the-size-of-a-child-widget-in-an-overlay-before-it-is-render/71962177#71962177), I had to modify flutter's source code to add the translucent behaviour to the popup barrier.

You can copy `routes.dart` into a new file `custom_routes.dart` and then in that file modify the function `_buildModalBarrier` of `ModalRoute` class like this (see the commented-out code):

```
  Widget _buildModalBarrier(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    else {
      ///////////////////////////////// comment this code
      // barrier = ModalBarrier(
      //   dismissible: barrierDismissible, // changedInternalState is called if barrierDismissible updates
      //   semanticsLabel: barrierLabel, // changedInternalState is called if barrierLabel updates
      //   barrierSemanticsDismissible: semanticsDismissible,
      // );
      //////////////////////////////// add this code
      barrier = Listener(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onPointerUp: (event){
            print('event is $event');
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
        },
      );
      ////////////////////////////////
    }
    ...
  }
```

#### But why not just create a Custom Route that extends `ModalRoute`?

You can do that but you need to re-implement all the logic that `ModalRoute` would have instead taken care of for you. So after hours of digging unfortunately this is the only way I found to do that. If someone has a better way tell me to update the answer.

---

Answer (score 2):

`ModalRoute` is described in the docs under the constructor as "a route that blocks interaction with previous routes". If you don't need all the magic that `ModalRoute` provides, you can extend `TransitionRoute` instead:

```dart
class TapThroughOverlayRoute<T> extends TransitionRoute<T> {
  final Duration _transitionDuration;
  final WidgetBuilder builder;

  TapThroughOverlayRoute({
    required this.builder,
    Duration transitionDuration = Duration.zero,
    super.settings,
  }) : _transitionDuration = transitionDuration;

  @override
  Iterable<OverlayEntry> createOverlayEntries() {
    return [OverlayEntry(builder: builder, maintainState: true)];
  }

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => _transitionDuration;
}
```

This will create a route that does not have any layers preventing interaction with previous routes.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue where I wanted to pass through all interaction beneath my custom extension of ModalRoute while it was visible. The caveat is that my solution takes away the *barrierColor* property. But in my use case, that was fine since I was making a more customizable replacement for SnackBar.

```
class FancyNotification extends ModalRoute<void> {

   // Rest of your code here      

   @override
   Widget buildModalBarrier() {
     return GestureDetector(
       behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
     );
   }
}
```